How to install cplex python API on mac os
I am using mac M1 with Sonoma 14.5 and trying to install the cplex warper for Python. CPLEX 22.1.1. is already installed on my machine and works with docplex, the IDE and oplrun.
When trying to install the "cplex" package under conda environment using
conda install ibmdecisionoptimization::cplex
which works perfectly under Linux. I get the message

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

- ibmdecisionoptimization::cplex

Current channels:

- https://conda.anaconda.org/nodefaults
- https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge
- defaults
- https://conda.anaconda.org/ibmdecisionoptimization

To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package you're
looking for, navigate to

    https://anaconda.org

and use the search bar at the top of the page.

Any ideas?
I tried it with conda environment of Python 3.9, 3.10 and 3.11.
Clearly, I checked the link above but it send me back to square one.
The same trick works well for the docplex package.
Any ideas?

It seems like that message should have given you an idea of what to do next.

Not at all. It suggests using the very same channel I used to begin with: ibmdecisionoptimization

It doesn't suggest any channels, it is listing your current channels, and then gives you directions to search for alternate channels.
